# How evaluate array path in string into real array path

Tags: php, arrays

I have following text string saved in variable `$path`:

```
$path = "['parent']['son']";
```

And I need to reach the content of following variable using the string above:

```
$_SESSION['parent']['son']
```

I guess I could use the `eval` function, but I'm unable to do it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'And I need to echo this variable within the string above'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for eval.
Explode the string and remove unwanted then loop the array and dig in the session array.

```
$path = "['parent']['son']"; 

$arr = explode("']['", $path);

$ret = $_SESSION;

foreach($arr as $val){
    $key = str_replace(["'", "]", "["], "", $val);
    $ret = $ret[$key];
}

var_dump($ret);
```

See working example:
https://3v4l.org/KgYOA

Also keep in mind that eval is not recommended unless you really really have to.
Usually there are ways to do the same thing with less dangerous functions, as I showed above.